# rails calling get request twice

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using rails 5 and I am trying to save an object to my db with some parameters on a get request. But for some reason my object is getting saved twice.
here is my code in controller

```
    class ParticipantCardController < ApplicationController

    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :authenticate_current_user_profile

    def participate
    # byebug
    params.permit(:event_id, :_method, :authenticity_token)
    event_id=params[:event_id].to_i
    byebug
        @new_participant = ParticipantCard.new
        @new_participant.user=current_user
        @new_participant.event_id=event_id
        @new_participant.name="  "
        @new_participant.description="  "
        @new_participant.save
    # end
    # flash[:error] = @new_participant.errors.messages

    end
```

this is code calls the insert sql query twice, like so:

[terminal query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bunv8.png)

Comment: i just found out that this behaviour is only occuring on firefoxDeveloperEdition. It is not happening on chrome